# How to avoid Rules adding blanks to eMail Id subscribed via Simplenews?

Tags: 7, rules, emails

The following rule works fine, only it adds always a blank before and after the emailaddress in the database table . And that gives an error when sending the newsletter.

```
{ "rules_webform_block_to_simplenews" : {
    "LABEL" : "Webform Block to simplenews",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "webform_rules", "rules", "simplenews_rules" ],
    "ON" : { "webform_rules_submit" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "webform_has_id" : {
          "form_id" : "webform-client-form-113",
          "selected_webform" : { "value" : { "webform-client-form-113" : "webform-client-form-113" } }
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "simplenews_rules_action_subscribe" : { "mail" : "[data:e_mail-value]", "tid" : "211", "confirmation" : "2" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention in your question what the data type is for that e_mail component. But you may want to experiment a bit to see if your problem is resolved by using token `[data:e_mail-value-raw]` instead of `[data:e_mail-value]`.

Here is a quote from the *description* (in the Rules UI) about such "raw" values:

> The raw value of the selected component, e.g. "email-value-raw". However this is not cleaned up by check_plain(). This is raw user input so take care if you use this somewhere else.

If the above doesn't help, I'd also check if adding (some or all of) these Rules Actions would help (before your existing rules Action):

- Add a variable, eg `email_id`
- Set a data value for that `email_id`, to assign it the value `[data:e_mail-value]`
- Convert data type of that `email_id` field (which you then use in your existing Rules Action).

Comment: it's an emailaddressfield

Comment: data:e_mail-value-raw solved the problem - thx